# Add Custom error message for wrong user name password using wp_login_form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wp_login_form()` function to create a login form. The problem is that if I enter wrong username/password or leave the fields empty, it redirects to the default Wordpress login page.

I want to display error messages at my template page. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'echo' => true,
'redirect' => site_url(),
    'form_id' => 'loginform',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username:' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password:' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in' => __('Login'),
    'id_username' => 'user_login',
    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
    'remember' => true,
    'value_username' => NULL,
    'value_remember' => false ); ?>
<?php  wp_login_form($args); ?>
```

Comment: check this [Link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-can-i-redirect-user-after-entering-wrong-passowrd) !!!

Answer (score -1):

See [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-from-wp-loginphp-to-login), it worked perfectly for me, I just search how to get error. :)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is a comment. Also this isn't at all what op is asking about.